# Does paypal vault support SEK (Sweden) currency?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

I am working on paypal integration using vault. But when I am calling payment API by passing "payment_method":"credit_card" with vault credit-card id return by vault credit-cards API and getting error from payment API **"Currency is not supported."**
**Note: using "currency":"SEK"**

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between supporting currency and vault. Paypal treats both differently as both are different modules. 
Its all because SEK is not in your currency list. Please add **SEK** as one of your currencies and give a try again.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: I have checked my account and SEK is in my currency list. For reference please see attached screen shot of my account. https://www.screencast.com/t/eDhxwIDbng1. Also please let me know is anything that I am missing or need to take care.